# Why my application does not consume CPU and RAM?

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, cpu-usage, stress-testing, throughput

I have a solution in asp.net-core 3.1. When I run stress testing, it consumes no more than 20-30% cpu.
I have tried increasing worker processes but still it gives a constant throughput and does not consume resources.
Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong here?

### System Specs:

OS: Windows server 2012
CPU: 16 cores
RAM: 64 GB

Comment: Why do you want it to consume more resources? Are you not getting the performance you want?

Comment: Yes, I need performance. It gives me around 115 RPS on single worker process with a concurrent requests of 300 (JMeter). As I have enough resources, I need it to utilize and server more requests per second.

Comment: Sounds like you have an I/O intensive workload either network I/O or disk I/O. An I/O heavy workload such as web servers, databases, streaming movie servers etc. will rarely consume more than 10% of CPU but will absolutely saturate the relevant I/O because 90% of the time the CPU will be waiting for data to be transferred. As such I/O heavy work depends more on good network or disk infrastructure more than CPU

Comment: Throwing cores or RAM at it only helps if the workload is CPU-bound. If CPU and RAM usage is constant and not maxing out, then @slebetman is right: the workload is I/O bound, in which case, you need a faster pipe or drive.

Comment: @slebetman, I do have I/O workload, plus request/response of each request is logged into database and it runs in a separate thread. Can you suggest any article that provides thorough content on heavy I/O, its impact and how to point it out while debugging?

Comment: @ChrisPratt How do I point out if I am having issues of network or database?

Comment: did you include application insights and see actually how many active requests at same time ..? then check  in JMeter the actual throughput of the requests .. Applicaiton insights is a good start to track the dependencies calls and how much they consume

Comment: @HanyHabib I did not try application insights but yeah, I think that can be done and it might help.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I integrated Application Insights and It helped me find bottle necks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same scenario before and Microsoft Application Insights was so helpful. It will show you

1. Actual Count of Active users
2. Memory / Cpu Usage
3. The Most Important One is the dependency tracking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies.

So if you have any dependency call for example http/database call having any performance issue it will appear.
For JMeter i tried to run the stress test from my local machine and found that i set for example 50 concurrent users but actually the ones hitting the application is only 20. So we needed to run the Jmeter from multiple machines.

Another Idea also you can turn off caching if you are caching the results so you are sure that your are always hitting the dependencies.

Comment: I integrated Microsoft Application Insights to my application and It helped me identify how slow was my dependency. After tuning it, I found out database was the bottle neck. Once I increased resources of my database, I got 470 Rquests Per Second and I fully utilized cpu. Thank you